# I simply wrote a vgg16 but it doesn't work

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

I have written a vgg16 for binary classification by myself with pytorch, I found that its outputs are same for the inputs in same batch,  after back propagation the outputs change but still same for data in same batch. I have no idea why this would happen. I tried vgg16 in torchvision and it works perfectly for the same dataset. So I'm sure there are some problems in my model.

Here is the code of my own model:

```py
class VGG16(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(VGG16, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(3, 64, padding=(1,1), kernel_size=(3,3))              #kernel
        self.conv2 = torch.nn.Conv2d(64, 64, padding=(1,1), kernel_size=(3,3))
        self.conv3 = torch.nn.Conv2d(64, 128, padding=(1,1), kernel_size=(3,3))
        self.conv4 = torch.nn.Conv2d(128, 128, padding=(1,1), kernel_size=(3,3))
        self.conv5 = torch.nn.Conv2d(128, 256, padding=(1,1), kernel_size=(3,3))
        self.conv6 = torch.nn.Conv2d(256, 256, padding=(1,1), kernel_size=(3,3))
        self.conv7 = torch.nn.Conv2d(256, 256, padding=(1,1), kernel_size=(3,3))
        self.conv8 = torch.nn.Conv2d(256, 512, padding=(1,1) ,kernel_size=(3,3))
        self.conv9 = torch.nn.Conv2d(512, 512, padding=(1,1), kernel_size=(3,3))
        self.conv10 = torch.nn.Conv2d(512, 512, padding=(1,1), kernel_size=(3,3))
        self.conv11 = torch.nn.Conv2d(512, 512, padding=(1,1), kernel_size=(3,3))
        self.conv12 = torch.nn.Conv2d(512, 512, padding=(1,1), kernel_size=(3,3))
        self.conv13 = torch.nn.Conv2d(512, 512, padding=(1,1), kernel_size=(3,3))
        self.pooling = torch.nn.MaxPool2d(2)                                        # pool
        self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(25088, 4096)                                     # 7 * 7 * 512 = 25088
        self.fc2 = torch.nn.Linear(4096, 4096)
        self.fc3 = torch.nn.Linear(4096, 2)
        self.Avgpool = torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((7, 7))
        self.ReLU = nn.ReLU(True)
        #self.Drop = nn.Dropout()

    def forward(self,x):
        batch_size = x.size(0)
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.ReLU(x)                                                #layer1
        x = self.pooling(self.ReLU(self.conv2(x)))                                  #layer2
        x = self.ReLU(self.conv3(x))                                                #layer3
        x = self.pooling(self.ReLU(self.conv4(x)))                                  #layer4
        x = self.ReLU(self.conv5(x))                                                #layer5
        x = self.ReLU(self.conv6(x))                                                #layer6
        x = self.pooling(self.ReLU(self.conv7(x)))                                  #layer7
        x = self.ReLU(self.conv8(x))                                                #layer8
        x = self.ReLU(self.conv9(x))                                                #layer9
        x = self.pooling(self.ReLU(self.conv10(x)))                                 #layer10
        x = self.ReLU(self.conv11(x))                                               #layer11
        x = self.ReLU(self.conv12(x))                                               #layer12
        x = self.pooling(self.ReLU(self.conv13(x)))                                 #layer13
        x = self.Avgpool(x)
        #x = x.view(batch_size,-1)                                               
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1)                                                   #flatten
        #print(x.shape)                                                           #for Debug
        #print(x)

        x = self.ReLU(self.fc1(x))
        #x = self.Drop(x)
        x = self.ReLU(self.fc2(x))
        #x = self.Drop(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        #x = F.sigmoid(x)
        return x
```

Here are the situations of outputs of the same batch:
[outputs for a batch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9CYD.png),
[outputs for another batch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvPg3.png)

This problem has been bothering me for days, I would be most grateful if you could point out my mistakes.

Here are some inputs with label 0:
[input1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXfzF.png),[input2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kAOB.png)[input3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qg2rR.png)
inputs with label 1:
[input4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aOpM.png),[input5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ocmwa.png)[input6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWcRf.png)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Ok, I have uploaded 6 input pictures, you can set the bs = 3 to see model's behavior(Gives the same outputs)

Comment: VGG is a pretty big model, since you use ReLU it is possible that the data is zeroed out in one or more of the layers. How long did you train it for?

Comment: 2-3 hours for 10 epoch. I use ReLU because the vgg16 in torchvision uses it, My vgg16 is almost same as which in torchvision, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
def _initialize_weights(self):
    for m in self.modules():
        if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
            nn.init.kaiming_normal_(
                m.weight, mode='fan_out', nonlinearity='relu')
            if m.bias is not None:
                nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)
        elif isinstance(m, nn.Linear):
            nn.init.normal_(m.weight, 0, 0.01)
            nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)
```

I faced the same error, try this out, It worked for me, Call this function in __init__